# Postgresql: in a link table check a condition on inserted values among related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema like this one:

```sql
create table users (

  id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
  name text not null

);

create table feature (

  id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
  value text not null check (value != '')

);

create unique index ux1 on feature(value);

-- link table
create table user_feature (

  id bigint generated always as identity,
  user_id bigint not null references users(id),
  feature_id bigint not null references feature(id)
);

create unique index ux2 on user_feature(user_id, feature_id);

-- feature values
insert into feature (value) values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D');
```

So an user can have 0 or more features, he can have just one type of same feature but I would like add some logic/conditions between the features that an user can have.

For example let's say feature `B` and `C` are incompatibles, so user can have none of them, `B` or `C` but not both, not `B` and `C` together.

What is, if there is, a proper way to do this ?

I was reading and if am not wrong the only option is a trigger right (on insert / update)?
I am not used to triggers, if someone can at least gives an example.

I am using version 14.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid triggers. If two users insert values B and C in separate transactions, your trigger won't catch it since each session will see only the value it inserted.

You can use a unique index with a case expression instead:

```
create unique index u3 on user_feature(user_id, 
                                       (case when feature_id in (2 /* B */, 3 /* C */) then 1 
                                             else null 
                                        end));
```

This unique index

- ignores any feature that is not B or C (provided that B has ID 2 and C has ID 3)
- prevents insertion of B and C for the same user (since they are mapped to the same value in the `CASE` expression

However, this approach is somewhat limited:

- your features need to adhere to an equivalence relation, i.e. if B and C are disallowed and C and D are disallowed, then B and D must be disallowed, as well
- your primary keys must be known at constraint creation time (I'd forego the `generated as identity` in that case and provide the PK values explicitly)

*UPDATE* As @res1 pointed out in their comment: the first limitation isn't really a problem because you can add a separate unique index for each combination you want to disallow.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0e71a/1)

Comment: Hi, can you clarify the first point of the limitation of this approach ? keeping the index you created, if I add another unique index as you indicate with C and D but returning 2 as value for the case, why I need to disallow B and D too ?

Comment: @res1 You're right, adding a separate unique index for each combination that you want to disallow should work. Hadn't thought of that, I was thinking more in terms of "one unique index to forbid them all" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you definitely need to enforce such behavior with triggers. Here is some example code for checking that a user cannot have feature B and C:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_feature_compatibility() RETURNS     TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
-- Check for conflicting features B and C
IF NEW.feature_id IN (SELECT id FROM feature WHERE value IN ('B', 'C')) THEN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_feature WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id 
           AND feature_id IN (SELECT id FROM feature WHERE value IN ('B', 'C'))
           AND id != NEW.id) THEN
               RAISE EXCEPTION 'User cannot have both feature B and C';
   END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER user_feature_check BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON user_feature
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION check_feature_compatibility();
```

**Behaviour:**

When updating a user with this data:

[image: user-data][image: error]

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how do you mange if it is an insert or an update

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you mean by "mange if its an insert or update". It does not matter if it's an insert or an update. And you can freely defined when the trigger should be executed. So you can just remove the UPDATE keyword in the trigger definition if it should only run when inserting a row.

Comment: I'd guess that this fails if session 1 inserts value B, session 2 inserts value C, and both sessions commit after that.

Comment: Yes when using transactions this is a race condition and the check could be bypassed.